# Make Enter insert a newline when the autocomplete word is fully typed

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-completion

In VSCode, when I type C# code like `else`, then I press Enter to go to the next line and type the `{` of the following block. But no new line is inserted. Instead, that autocomplete suggestions dropdown is closed and nothing else happens. I wasn't even looking at the screen and didn't care about that completion suggestion thing here. I just wanted to type some code and a part of it was ignored unexpectedly.

How can I stop this? When I press Enter after already fully typing the first suggestion, I want the Enter key to do its job, which is primarily insert a line break.

In Visual Studio there's an option for that but I couldn't find one in VSCode.